# .siblings() animating element css efficiently

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to have a click-able element "toggle"(for lack of a better phrase), two elements. I want to accomplish this using only classes.

When you click one of the "side" divs, I want one side to animate to 90% and the other to 10%.
-this I was able to accomplish using .siblings();

simultaneously— I would like to fade in the opacity of the main text while fading out the other. using the same technique as the above width "toggle" I am **unable** to achieve this and have no idea why.

looking at my code might help articulate the concept better—it's not a complex animation, I am making it more complicated by trying this with only classes as an exercise in efficiency as there might be an occasion where i want 600 divs of the same class to do this with one small block of code.

The animation is handled by TweenMax with jquery

I'm self taught and get things to work, but I'm completely oblivious to its efficiency, relevance, or best-practices. so Any help would be great. An explanation on why this isn't working would be awesome.

`

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id = 'title'>lorem</div>
            <div id = 'experienced'>
                <div id = 'left' class = 'side'>
                    <div class = 'texts'>asd;jhfa;djsf;ha;sdjf k;ajsdfjkhasdf   asdjhflakjsflhasd f asfdjkhasfdjhlhsfd</div>
                </div>
                <div id = 'right' class = 'side'>
                    <div class = 'texts'>asd;jhfa;djsf;ha;sdjf k;ajsdfjkhasdf   asdjhflakjsflhasd f asfdjkhasfdjhlhsfd
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

<style>
#experienced{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
}

.side{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.texts{
    opacity: 0;    
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding 50px;
    color: white;
}

#left{
    background-color: red;
}

#right{
    background-color: green;
}


</style>
<script>


    $( ".side" ).click(function() {

var toggleClassThis = this;
var toggleClass = $(this).siblings(".side");
var toggleClassThisText = $(this).find(".texts");
var toggleClassText = $(toggleClassThis).find(".texts").siblings(toggleClassThisText);

        TweenLite.to(toggleClassThis, .5, {width:"90%",ease:Expo.easeOut});
        TweenLite.to(toggleClass, .5, {width:"10%",ease:Expo.easeOut});
        TweenLite.to(toggleClassThisText, .5, {alpha:"1", ease:Expo.easeOut});
        TweenLite.to(toggleClassText, .5, {alpha:"0", ease:Expo.easeOut});
    });
</script>

</html>
```

`

http://codepen.io/filthysanches/pen/KwQvRy

Comment: Sure that the property to animate for this is called `alpha` (dunno, I am not familiar with TweenLite) – and not just the standard CSS `opacity` property?

Comment: Is the plugin necessary for your animation? Accomplishing what you describe shouldn't be too complicated with just jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
var toggleClassText = $(toggleClassThis).find(".texts").siblings(toggleClassThisText);
```

to

```
var toggleClassText = $(toggleClass).find(".texts");
```

Because you already found the object using toggleClass.

```
$( ".side" ).click(function() {

var toggleClassThis = this;
var toggleClass = $(this).siblings(".side");
var  toggleClassThisText = $(this).find(".texts");
var toggleClassText = $(toggleClass).find(".texts");

    TweenLite.to(toggleClassThis, .5, {width:"90%",ease:Expo.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(toggleClass, .5, {width:"10%",ease:Expo.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(toggleClassThisText, .5, {alpha:"1", ease:Expo.easeOut});
    TweenLite.to(toggleClassText, .5, {alpha:"0", ease:Expo.easeOut});
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNQZqW

Answer (score 0):

Nice this is just what I was looking for. It seems as though I tried that, but I guess I just missed it. As for the TweenLite engine. It is not necessary for the animation, however, it is an extremely powerful tweening engine. It handles animation and timeline triggered animation very well, and more off the amount of different types of tweens are un-paralleled. Thats why i use tweenmax/tweenlite, that and it condenses multiple lines of code, into just one. It has its own syntax that is carried over from its flash days, which is why its alpha and not opacity, though it manipulates opacity in this case—probably for continuity between the actionscript and javascript tweening engines. If you haven't checked it out you might want to… [or not up to you tweenmax](http://greensock.com/gsap) Thanks for all the help much appreciated.